# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I am having an xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fcd-export>
    <timestep time="21600.00">
        <vehicle id="35092_35092_353" x="15957.04" y="6766.28" angle="-20.81" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="-25585097_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="39328_39328_360" x="17130.05" y="19503.58" angle="10.26" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="23839407#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="41136_41136_361" x="9060.15" y="16419.84" angle="-4.45" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="20683992#1_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="44930_44930_362" x="9219.87" y="14016.02" angle="-100.00" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="-157393121#3_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="48989_48989_366" x="14834.41" y="16869.85" angle="-171.25" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="49292083#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
    </timestep>
    <timestep time="21601.00">
        <vehicle id="35092_35092_353" x="15956.44" y="6764.72" angle="-20.81" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="1.67" pos="6.27" lane="-25585097_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="36884_36884_357" x="7568.78" y="14312.49" angle="89.14" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="75656253_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="39197_39197_360" x="19736.51" y="20503.63" angle="-114.77" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="25413481#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="39328_39328_360" x="17130.40" y="19501.65" angle="10.26" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="1.96" pos="6.56" lane="23839407#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="41136_41136_361" x="9059.96" y="16417.31" angle="-4.45" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="2.54" pos="7.14" lane="20683992#1_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="41383_41383_361" x="17941.36" y="14232.66" angle="100.09" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="42551572#3_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="41720_41720_361" x="17601.61" y="12980.92" angle="68.50" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="132408336#3_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="42276_42276_361" x="5391.08" y="13878.96" angle="79.21" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="0.00" pos="4.60" lane="135556243#2_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="44930_44930_362" x="9218.45" y="14016.27" angle="-100.00" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="1.44" pos="6.04" lane="-157393121#3_0" slope="0.00"/>
        <vehicle id="48989_48989_366" x="14834.16" y="16871.66" angle="-171.89" type="passenger_P_14_1" speed="1.83" pos="6.43" lane="49292083#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
    </timestep>
</fcd-export>
```

I am trying to use the `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE` command to import the file (size=7.4GB) into a mysql table. I am trying to avoid to create myself the structure of the table..

Any help, would be great!!

Comment: MySQL can only load data from XML files, not schema.  There are third party ETL tools which can convert XML schema into DDL statements, but using MySQL's native tools you will have to create the table by hand (as shown in my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    time    DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
    id      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    x       DECIMAL(7,2),
    y       DECIMAL(7,2),
    angle   DECIMAL(5,2),
    type    VARCHAR(255),
    speed   DECIMAL(3,2),
    pos     DECIMAL(3,2),
    lane    VARCHAR(255),
    slope   DECIMAL(3,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(time, id)
);

LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/data.xml'
    INTO TABLE vehicles
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<vehicle>';
```